# Authentication during GET request with Basic Auth

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, basic-authentication

I have a spring app, which is hidden behind the proxy. App requires authentication on the start screen (log in form). Proxy also requires authentication (basic auth). Let assume that I cannot get rid of proxy.
Obvious idea is to not force users to log in twice (credentials are usualy the same).
However, that would mean, that users would be authenticated with GET request (using basic auth), which seems a bad idea, so I have few questions:

1. Is it a generally not-so-bad idea to authenticate users during GET request ?
2. I still try to implement it by my own with spring authentication filters, however I want to ask if this a good approach? For log in form I have my own `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and also my own endpoint which handles authentication (which basically sets a cookie).
   I assume that for my case I would have to have second `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which will authenticate users through basic auth using authentication filter ?
   If yes, is there a way to set ant matchers only once ? Otherwise how I see it, is that I will have to set the request matchers for both Configurations which of course some day may lead to inconsistency ?

Comment: *1. Is it a generally not-so-bad idea to authenticate users during GET request ?* The HTTP verb isn't important. The question is what URLs should be protected. If an URL should be protected, some kind of authentication is neccessary.

Comment: *2. I still try to implement it by my own with spring authentication filters, however I want to ask if this a good approach?* No, it isn't. All you need already exists, you could use Spring Security's classes.

Comment: *I assume that for my case I would have to have second WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter which will authenticate users through basic auth using authentication filter ?* No, in general (I don't know your configuration) you could use the same one.

Comment: Thank you for answers @dur, regarding what you have wrote - when user enters through proxy, he the most probably is logged out so normally he will be redirected to login page, which is not protected. My idea was to authenticate him before the request hits point when redirect logic happens (logged in users are redirected to the app) in filter. And I'm using existing spring security filter however that still doesn't work. I'm afraid that what I want to do (set cookie in GET request for html) is just impossible. I might be wrong though, but cookie is not being set.